# Taking pictures without requiring an SD card

Tags: android

The android documentation shows you how to capture an image and save into EXTERNAL storage, but I want my app to work even if the user DOESN'T have an SD card. **I only need to temporary save the file until I upload it.**

So I create a file as such and pass the URI through the intent to the camera app:

```
File imgfile = new File(getFilesDir(), imageFileName);
imgfile.setReadable(true, false);
imgfile.createNewFile();

Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, IMAGE_PICKER_TAKE);
```

But after I take the picture and hit OK, the Camera app never returns to my app. I'm guessing this is because it cannot accesss the file I passed to it becuase it is in the directory returned by getFilesDir(), which I think is not supposed to be readable by other apps. I tried setting setReadable(), but it didnt fix it. Is there another directory in internal storage I can use?

*** OR is there a way I can tell the the camera app to save the pic in its own file directory, and pass me a URI that I can read with a contentResolver (the way I do when I select a pic from gallery). ***

Comment: External storage has nothing to do with a removable SD card. Well not today. getFilesDir() is internal private memory and not accessable for other aps. Just go use external files dir.

Comment: @greenapps So your saying on newer devices, even if the user doesn't have an SD card, external memory is available to them?

Comment: Correct. Yes. Indeed.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you. If you add this as an answer, I will except it as as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External storage has nothing to do with a removable SD card. Well not today. getFilesDir() is internal private memory and not accessable for other aps. Just go use external files dir.